# How much fresh lovage in soup?

Tags: herbs, soup

My friend just gave me two [lovage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lovage) leaves and I am planning on making chicken soup (from bouillon crystals) with it. My question is how much lovage should I put in? Also should I leave them whole, chop them or crush them....

**Update**: I was thinking about throwing it in the soup like I understand you would a bay leaf. How long should it be in the soup. What ratio lovage to broth amount. Should the leaves be whole, chopped, crushed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would shred one or both leaves (depending on size) and garnish the soup right before eating it.

Answer (score 2):

Lovage is used like parsley, not like bay leaf. Just season with the fresh leaves, minced or roughly chopped, towards the end of cooking.

As for an amount, I can't give you that much guidance. It is a strong-smelling herb, so use it more sparingly than parsley or mint. You can always add more if you don't find it enough.